# Hibernate issue " Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1"

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate

I'm using Jersey + spring + hibernate4.17 to develop api system； The problem is if the cleaFields is called twice at same time, the 2nd call will throw an exception as below,

```
org.hibernate.StaleStateException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.Expectations$BasicExpectation.checkBatched(Expectations.java:81)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.Expectations$BasicExpectation.verifyOutcome(Expectations.java:73)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.BatchingBatch.checkRowCounts(BatchingBatch.java:133)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.BatchingBatch.performExecution(BatchingBatch.java:110)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.BatchingBatch.doExecuteBatch(BatchingBatch.java:101)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.AbstractBatchImpl.execute(AbstractBatchImpl.java:149)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.executeBatch(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:162)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:357)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:280)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:326)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:52)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1213)
```

The clearFields method in the Controller,

```
@Transactional(isolation=Isolation.REPEATABLE_READ)
public void clearFields(Integer userId) {
    User user = this.userDao.get(userId);
    user.getFields().clear();
    userDao.flush(); //call the current session.flush(); this line can throw exception.
}
```

User Entity class

```
@Entity
@Table(name="users")
@NamedQuery(name="User.findAll", query="SELECT u FROM User u")

public class User implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private int userId;


    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = { CascadeType.ALL }, targetEntity = UserProfile.class, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval=true)
    @OrderBy("id")
    private List<UserProfile> fields = new ArrayList<UserProfile>();

    public User() {
    }

    public int getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(int userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public List<UserProfile> getFields() {
        return fields;
    }

    public void setFields(List<UserProfile> fields) {
        this.fields = fields;
    }

}
```

UserProfile class,

```
@Entity
@Table(name="user_profiles")
public class UserProfile implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;


    @Column(name="field_name")
    private String fieldName;


    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = User.class, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="user_id")
    private User user;

    private String value;


    public UserProfile() {

    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }


    public String getFieldName() {
        return this.fieldName;
    }

    public void setFieldName(String fieldName) {
        this.fieldName = fieldName;
    }


    public String getValue() {
        return this.value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }


    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

}
```

I did some research, the root cause is if the 2nd calling get some fields, and before  delete them, the 1st calling already delete all fields from database.

In another word, the 2nd calling try to delete some records which already were deleted by others.

How can I solve the problem?

Comment: View code which contain error? Not to post all code here.

Comment: Why do you manually flush the session at that point?

Comment: Actually, there is some following code, which adds some fields, so I want to clear all old fields, and then add new fields.

Comment: I solved the issue by using the lock LockMode.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE when query the User object; I don't know if there is a better solution; but anyway, the solution works.